# HL7 messages dealing with surgical procedures

Tags: hl7-v2

I need to change an existing system (written in Python using python-hl7) to accept messages with details of a surgical procedure for a patient and then record those details in a database as part of their medical record.  This question is more about HL7 (v2) than Python or python-hl7, though.  I couldn't find a better Stack Exchange "community" to post this in.

What message types, segments should be used to record details of a surgical procedure.  e.g. what procedure was done, when it started and ended, what the outcome was, where it took place, who the primary and assistant surgeons were, etc.

From what I've been able to find so far it seems some sort of ADT message (e.g. A04) with a PR1 segment should be used.  Is this correct?  Are there example messages?

Thanks.

EDIT: To be clear I am not looking for Python examples.  I am looking for sample HL7 messages to get an idea of how other people do it.  Of course clear and unambiguous documentation that says exactly what fields are required and exactly what they can/should contain would also help.

Comment: I don't know what's the answer, but instead of trying to find some python-code or `hl7` message examples (unlikely to be accessible to internet search), I'd try to dig in specifications provided by [ihe.net](http://ihe.net/) and [hl7.org](http://www.hl7.org/). Except for `surgical procedure` search keyword (and it's declensions) I guess that `workflow` search keyword might reveal a path to follow

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that you can find a single message that covers everything related to surgery (ORU is the closest one). In general surgery is type of Act similar to other events that may happen with the patient. For that reason you need to decide what you are looking for since a “surgery” can be divided into admission/discharge/transfer (ADT), scheduling (SIU, OMS), patient summary (MDM), preoperative (MFN, ORU), intraoperative (ORU, DFT), postoperative (ORU, MDM, DFT, MFN).

Exact type and place of the surgery can be specified by ICD-10 or SNOMED CT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm interested in postop, i.e. what surgery was done (yes, ICD10/SNOMED CT should do, as long as I know which message type, segment, field it should be in :)
Also, when the surgery started, ended, where it happened, outcome etc.
So I was thinking an ADT^A04 might work with PV1-3 possibly being used for the location? But maybe that's a bad idea. I don't know.
For postop you mention ORU, MDM, DFT, MFN, all of which I'm not really familiar with. How should I decide between them?

Comment: @Wodin Check ORU_R01 message, that's Chapter 7 of the HL7v2 spec.